# Can we use Bellman-ford algorithm for a graph containing multiple sources?

Tags: graph

we know that we can use Dijkstra Algorithm for graph containing multiple sources for example [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multi-source-shortest-path-in-unweighted-graph/) problem can be solved by using multiple Dijkstra's algorithm for multiple sources. Similarly, can we implement
Bellman-ford algorithm ? If possible share pseudo code.

Assume that the graph contains negative weight edges and no negative cycles.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a computer science question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

Sure! One simple way to do this is to turn the original graph, which has multiple sources, into a new graph with exactly one source. Just add in a new node s that has zero-cost directed edges to each of the sources from the original graph. Running Bellman-Ford starting at this new node s then effectively simulates finding shortest paths starting from each of the sources.